# Why the order of the fearures affects synapse LightGBM predictions?

Tags: classification, feature-selection, data-science-model, lightgbm

I am using LighGBM Classifier and Regressor and it seems that the order of the features I am adding, affect the predictions of the model. Everytime I change the order, another result comes up and with a big difference from the previous one.
I tried multiple changes in the order of the columns. For example for the classifier while changing the order of the features I came up with count of rows for prediction=1 from 9000 rows to 200 rows which is really different. I have the same order in train set and test set. Can this somehow be fixed?Is there a way to handle this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> *the order of the features ... affect the predictions of the model*

LightGBM's model representation refers to features by their positional index. When passing in data to generate predictions, that data must have the same number of columns as the training data, in the same order.

> *I have the same order in train set and test set*

I understood this statement to mean that you mean that you're shuffling the column order in data being passed in to generate predictions.

HOWEVER... if you actually mean that you're getting different trained models when you vary the order of the training-data columns, then that might mean one of the following is be happening:

- some of the columns have identical or near-identical values
- you are using some parameters like `interaction_constraints` ([link](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#interaction_constraints)) or `monotone_constraints` ([link](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#monotone_constraints)) which accept lists of feature indices, and you aren't changing those as you shuffle the training columns